# how to preserveAspectRatio SVG Icomoon

Tags: html, css, svg

How are you doing! Got a rare issue I guess cause cant find any answer on the internet so far.

Im using Icomoon to store my svg library and load them via CDN in to my projects. However, I want to use a SVG as like a background and need it to strech on VW. But seems preserveAspectRatio="none" is not working on this way because Icomoon is generating its HTML like:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" class="icon icon-navigation_top-bar">
<use xlink:href="#icon-navigation_top-bar" style="width: 100vw;"></use>
</svg>
```

So this wont work for me I guess? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an icon

```html
<svg width="100" height="50"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       
      <path id="icon"  d="M27.981,41.947c0.001,0.019,0.006,0.036,0.006,0.056C27.987,44.21,26.202,46,24,46
 s-3.987-1.79-3.987-3.997c0-0.019,0.005-0.036,0.005-0.056C7.267,41.597,4,39.52,4,37.003c0-0.788,0.344-1.53,1.181-2.194
 C11.209,28.094,13,29.953,13,20.006c0-6.632,0.271-12.712,8.258-13.807C21.1,5.833,21.01,5.431,21.01,5.008
 c0-1.656,1.339-2.998,2.99-2.998s2.99,1.342,2.99,2.998c0,0.423-0.09,0.825-0.248,1.191C34.729,7.294,35,13.374,35,20.006
 c0,9.977,1.8,8.073,7.872,14.86C43.666,35.516,44,36.237,44,37.003C44,39.518,40.647,41.595,27.981,41.947z M24,44.003
 c1.102,0,1.994-0.895,1.994-1.998c0-0.006-0.002-0.012-0.002-0.018c-0.651,0.009-1.296,0.019-1.992,0.019s-1.34-0.01-1.992-0.019
 c0,0.006-0.002,0.012-0.002,0.018C22.006,43.108,22.898,44.003,24,44.003z M24,4.007c-0.551,0-0.996,0.447-0.996,0.999
 s0.445,1,0.996,1s0.997-0.448,0.997-1S24.551,4.007,24,4.007z M41.605,36.414c0,0-1.522-1.714-4.018-3.984
 C34.179,29.325,33,27.853,33,20.006c0-7.664-0.418-12-9-12s-9,4.336-9,12c0,7.848-1.18,9.321-4.59,12.427
 c-2.447,2.229-3.986,3.942-3.986,3.942C6,36.712,6,36.908,6,37.003c0,0.123,0.205,3.003,18,3.003s18-2.88,18-3.003
 C42,36.923,42,36.736,41.605,36.414z">
   </path>
    </svg>
```

To make it adaptive, you must remove the width and height of `viewport` `width ="100"` `"height ="50"` and add `viewBox =" 0 0 100 50"`

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
       
      <path id="icon"  d="M27.981,41.947c0.001,0.019,0.006,0.036,0.006,0.056C27.987,44.21,26.202,46,24,46
 s-3.987-1.79-3.987-3.997c0-0.019,0.005-0.036,0.005-0.056C7.267,41.597,4,39.52,4,37.003c0-0.788,0.344-1.53,1.181-2.194
 C11.209,28.094,13,29.953,13,20.006c0-6.632,0.271-12.712,8.258-13.807C21.1,5.833,21.01,5.431,21.01,5.008
 c0-1.656,1.339-2.998,2.99-2.998s2.99,1.342,2.99,2.998c0,0.423-0.09,0.825-0.248,1.191C34.729,7.294,35,13.374,35,20.006
 c0,9.977,1.8,8.073,7.872,14.86C43.666,35.516,44,36.237,44,37.003C44,39.518,40.647,41.595,27.981,41.947z M24,44.003
 c1.102,0,1.994-0.895,1.994-1.998c0-0.006-0.002-0.012-0.002-0.018c-0.651,0.009-1.296,0.019-1.992,0.019s-1.34-0.01-1.992-0.019
 c0,0.006-0.002,0.012-0.002,0.018C22.006,43.108,22.898,44.003,24,44.003z M24,4.007c-0.551,0-0.996,0.447-0.996,0.999
 s0.445,1,0.996,1s0.997-0.448,0.997-1S24.551,4.007,24,4.007z M41.605,36.414c0,0-1.522-1.714-4.018-3.984
 C34.179,29.325,33,27.853,33,20.006c0-7.664-0.418-12-9-12s-9,4.336-9,12c0,7.848-1.18,9.321-4.59,12.427
 c-2.447,2.229-3.986,3.942-3.986,3.942C6,36.712,6,36.908,6,37.003c0,0.123,0.205,3.003,18,3.003s18-2.88,18-3.003
 C42,36.923,42,36.736,41.605,36.414z">
   </path>
    </svg>

</div>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

> The preserveAspectRatio attribute indicates how an element with a
>   viewBox providing a given aspect ratio must fit into a viewport with a
>   different aspect ratio.

The value of the attribute preserveAspectRatio = "none" violates the preservation of proportions. 
Therefore, if you need to preserve the proportions of the image, then this value (`none`) should not be used. 
By default, this attribute has `preserveAspectRatio =" xMinYMid meet "`

Comment: Hi there and first of all thank you for your answer, however this is not what I need. Because when you use Icomoon you can import it like a CDN. So I need to use <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" class="icon icon-navigation_top-bar">
<use xlink:href="#icon-navigation_top-bar" style="width: 100vw;"></use>
</svg>. If I set the parameter preserveAspectRatio it wont work because after you check the browser it will generate a new HTML for you. So you dont have the possibility to set the preserve. Only thing I can imagine is to check it with jquery or so and set the parameter afterwards.

Comment: @dutchsociety Hi Do not set the parameter `preserveAspectRatio =" none "` it is not needed in your case. 
Do the rest manually according to my instructions and you will have responsive icons.

Comment: Oke thank you for you quick response, will check it out tomorrow.. If its working you will receive the green check :D.

Comment: Like I said before this isnt the answer, found out it is a bit more complex however you can find it in the config from the Icomoon settings of the CDN.